# Как добавить/удалить класс, при наведении, и вернуть его элементу по умолчанию?

Tags: javascript

Как при hover на tho или three, добавить класс active, и удалить его у one, а когда елемент не в hover, удалить класс active, и вернуть его one. По принципу как в вкладках.

```
<ul>
  <li class="item one active">1</li>
  <li class="item two">2</li>
  <li class="item three">3</li>
</ul>
```

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.item {
  color: black;  
}
.active {
 color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так

```js
const itemsBox = document.querySelector('.items-list')
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
const defaultActive = document.querySelector('.one')

itemsBox.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeaveHandler)
elements.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnterHandler))

function onMouseEnterHandler(e) {
  removeAllActive()
  const element = e.target.closest('.item')
  element.classList.add('active')
}

function onMouseLeaveHandler() {
  removeAllActive()
  defaultActive.classList.add('active')
}

function removeAllActive() {
  elements.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'))
}
```

```css
.items-list {
  display: flex
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.item.active {
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="items-list">
  <div class="item one active">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Тогда могу предложить такой вариант:

```js
const [firstLi, ...otherLis] = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

firstLi.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  firstLi.classList.add('active');
})

otherLis.forEach(li => {
  li.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    firstLi.classList.remove('active');
    li.classList.add('active');
  });
  
  li.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    firstLi.classList.add('active');
    li.classList.remove('active');
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item {
  color: black;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item one active">1</li>
  <li class="item two">2</li>
  <li class="item three">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Это я упростил задачу, что бы как то объяснить, что мне нужно реализовать. Что бы уже на основе это крутить продолжать. Тут вся соль в том, что нужно что бы первый был активный, когда все остальные не а hover.

Comment: @КонстантинЖевжик Обновил ответ, если вдруг понадобится :)